# How can we get current location/city of user without asking for permission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, ip

We wanted to get user's current location(maybe by tracking IP address or MAC address) whenever user does come on our website without asking any permission. So, does anyone know about it or have done it in past accurately?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like https://www.maxmind.com/en/home for IP geo location lookup via their API (https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/)

Comment: I have tried your recommended service, but it's not accurate enough. It's showing different city names on every browser refresh. Can you suggest me some better if you know anything else ?